# Pass certificate to j2me

Tags: java, encryption, java-me

I created a certificate on apache server.
x.509 public key certificate RSA created using the keytool

I need to pass this to a J2me app, via http. So the J2me app can encrypt data

How do I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise first reading the specifications of [JSR-177](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=177).

If it isn't available on the phones you target, the code you will need to write would be related to an implementation of the javax.microedition.pki.UserCredentialManager class.